# Помогите решить такую задачу

Tags: php, алгоритм

Необходимо сделать генератор билетов лото. Всё бы ничего если бы не дополнительные параметры. Вот собственно сама задача:

- Билет включает в себя 15 чисел от 1 до 99.
- Цифры разбиты на 3 строки и 10 столбцов, таким образом, что в первый столбец любой строки попадают числа от 1 до 9, во второй от 10 до 19, в третий от 20 до 29 и т.д.
- При создании билета нужно учитывать, что в каждой строке генерируется по 5 чисел (с учетом расположения по столбцам).
- В рамках одного билета числа не должны повторяться.

Сколько не пробовал, всё время не получается сделать так чтобы все условия указанные в задачи выполнялись. У меня есть три неполных решения:

либо числа не нужного диапазона в столбцах,

```
код
```

либо числа повторяются,

```
код
```

либо нету пропусков (всего 10 ячеек, из них 5 имеют числа, остальные должны быть пустые).

```
код
```

Comment: А почему вы свой код не выложили?

Comment: Покажите, что у вас сейчас уже получилось, какой код есть? У нас тут так принято, что мы не делаем полностью лабы за студентов, но можем помочь найти в конкретном коде конкретную ошибку. Вот вы пишете, что у вас что-то происходит не так, как хотите. Опубликуйте этот код, который делает не так.

Comment: Я сделал шаблон, замените `код` на, собственно, код.

Answer (score 1):

Просто сыграйте в лотто - возьмите 100 бочонков, положите в мешок, перемешайте, достаньте 15, расставьте по билету.

```
  $a = range (1, 99);
  shuffle($a);
  $a = array_slice($a, 0, 15);
```

Осталось расставить по столбцам. Писал с телефона, мог ошибиться

Ах да, три строки

```
   Array_chunk($a, 5);
```

Comment: У вас в `Array_chunk` опечатка. Первая буква должна быть строчной.

Comment: А способ-то не пройдет ;) Условие про максимум 3 числа из любого десятка не будет выполнятся.